# How to do password validation with regex?

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

Conditions :
Passwords must have at least 8 characters, which combine the use of at least 2 of the following: upper and lower case letters, numbers, and special characters.

Which pattern can fit with conditions?

Comment: What are the actual `special characters`?

Comment: You don't use a regular expressions for this.

Comment: I personally think this password policy sucks. "Special" characters are easy for machines to guess and very hard for people to remember. [xkcd/936](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: I agree with naomik. Most people will just write it down and have it sitting near their desk, which actually ends being less secure.

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions are the completely wrong approach for this. Instead simply count the number of occurrences of each character type and then simply use if statements and boolean logic to check if your requirements are met.

However, reconsider if what you want to do is a good idea:

- Restricting the symbols is a horribly bad idea. Any character should be allowed
- When the password has a certain length, requiring e.g. symbols/numbers/mixed-case loses lots of its purpose. Additionally an attacker cannot know if some user uses just lowercase chars or just digits in his password and thus he cannot tune a brute-force attack to use only those chars - and since you'll hopefully be throttling incorrect logins brute-force is not a good option anyway.
- Imagine "correct horse battery staple" from the famous [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/936/). While all those words are in a dictionary and might even fail a improperly implemented password check, it's very secure. While a single dictionary word is extremely insecure multiple of them will be easy to remember and secure (an attacker would have to try all e.g. 4-word combinations which are A DAMN LOT even with just a 1000 word dictionary).

So a much better password policy would:

- Reject obviously bad sequences. That's consecutive digits like 12345 or 54321. qwertz, qwerty, etc. are also bad.
- Reject any password that can be found in a dictionary as a whole. Make sure to use both an english dictionary and one for each language your site supports.
- Reject any other password that is likely to be insecure. Contains the username (even if backwards)? Nope. Contains the part before the @ of the user's email address? Nope. Contains his birthdate? Nope.
- Require at least 8 characters (as you already intend to do).

There's also an interesting post on the IT Security Stack Exchange site which you should read: [Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/427)

Comment: Yes i was thinking of doing it with boolean loging too, but will this do the trick for finding out if the password has any symbol    if (!password.Any(c => char.IsSymbol(c)))

Answer (score 0):

```
string PASSWORD_PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20})";
string password = "Password@1#";
Regex.IsMatch(password,PASSWORD_PATTERN);
```

try this.

Comment: Your solution lacks an explanation or demonstration that it works as intended.